# Occasionally error ASP NET 4.0 Could not load file or assembly 'App_Web_yqqnks55' using F5 load balancer

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, iis-7.5

I get the following error when i deploy new code to our web servers

Could not load file or assembly 'App_Web_yqqnks55, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 
PublicKeyToken=null' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Each server is accessed via a F5 load balancer. I have elmah running so i know which server the error originated from. When I access using the load balancer i get the error, i then go to the web server directly and the error doesn't occur. I retry the load balancer and the error reoccurs. This will happen a few times and then go away.

The web site is pre-compiled. Compilation in the web.config is

```
<compilation debug="false" batch="false"> 
        <assemblies>
        </assemblies>
    </compilation>
```

I've had a look around and there appears to be a hotfix but as far as i can tell it only applies to .NET 2.0.

It will be difficult to delete the temporary asp.net files because there are other websites running on the same web server.

Any ideas of what else i could try?

Comment: After doing a deployment, do you do an IISReset?

Comment: No i don't call IISReset because other websites are hosting on the same webserver. Also, i forgot to mention that we stop the web site and app pool before copying the new files to the web server.

Comment: This question was asked 3 years ago but was there ever a solution reached?

Comment: The site wasn't pre-compiled before deployment. The new code was deployed and each server compiled the code using different temporary names. And because sticky session weren't no used on the load balancer errors occurred when requests were sent to different servers in the server pool.